# Does Appium push bootstrap.jar to Android device automatically?

Tags: appium

When does Appium push `bootstrap.jar` to a device? Must one push `bootstrap.jar` manually?

Comment: this might help http://executeautomation.com/blog/how-appium-works/

Answer (score 1):

Appium will push the bootstrap jar to the realdevice. You can find the below in logs during execution.

info: [debug] Pushing appium bootstrap to device...

info: [debug] executing cmd: /Applications/Test/android_adt/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s a8e79692 push "/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/android_bootstrap/AppiumBootstrap.jar" /data/local/tmp/